# Creating a connected undirected graph with connectivity k

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, computer-science, computational-mathematics

I am working on a computing mini-project and I am stuck because of the following problem:

"Given a number of nodes N and a connectivity k such that $N > k + 1$, is it always possible to construct a *connected* graph in which each node has *exactly* k *undirected* links  to other nodes?"

If it's not always possible, what are the restrictions? Can you think of any algorithm I could use to create a NxN Hermitian connectivity matrix in which I store a zero if the nodes are not connected and a one if they are connected? (N.B. The matrix has to be Hermitian because the links are undirected.)

I'm really stuck and the deadline is approaching, so any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean a $k$-regular graph that is $k$-connected? Or do mean a $k$-regular graph that is connected (but not necessarily $k$-connected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to construct a $k$-regular graph that is $k$-connected, where the number $n$ of vertices is arbitrarily large. There are a few ways to go about doing this. This is a *sketch* of one way.

**For $k$ even** the number $n$ of vertices may be even or odd. Let $G$ be a graph where the vertex-set is $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}= \{0,1,\ldots, n-1 \}$, where $i$ is adjacent to each $j$ s.t. either $j-i$ or $i-j$ is $\left\{1, \ldots, \frac{k}{2}\right\}$ where all arithmetic is done mod $n$.

So for $k=2$ the graph $G$ is a cycle on $n$ vertices.

**For $k$ odd** the number $n$ of vertices must be even. Let $G$ be a graph where the vertex-set is $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, where $i$ is adjacent to each $j$ s.t. either $i-j \in \left\{1, \ldots, \left\lfloor \frac{k}{2} \right\rfloor \right\}$, or $j=i + \frac{n}{2}$ where all arithmetic is done mod $n$.

Comment: Dear Mike, thank you very much for your reply. Unfortunately I only know the very basics of graph theory (this project is part of a computational physics course), so I don't fully understand your reply. Could you explain a bit more what you mean when you say "where i is adjacent to each j s.t. i−j∈{1,…,k2} where all arithmetic is done mod n"? I believe the k-regular graph should be k-connected.

Comment: For example suppose $k$ is 4 and  the number $n$ of vertices is 21. Then number the vertices 0,1,...,20, and for each $i, j$ in 0,1,..., 21 put an edge between the vertex labelled $i$ and that labeled $j$ iff $i-j$ is either -2,-1,1,2 arithmetic done mod 21. For example  the vertex labelled 5 is adjacent to the vertices labelled 3,4,6, and 7. The vertex labelled 20 is adjacent to the vertices labelled 18,19,21, and 1 because 1 - 20 is 2 mod 21.

Comment: Meanwhile no, not all $k$-regular graphs are $k$-connected.